# Can a QGIS GeoJSON vector layer be held in-memory?

Tags: qgis, geojson, in-memory

When I add a vector layer to QGIS using data in GeoJSON format, data from the server are being displayed. The problem is that every change of the map extent (pan, zoomIn, ZomOut) is causing a request for the same data again.

Can the GeoJSON layer requested from the server be cached or held in-memory?